# Regular Expression (Hyphens, Underscores, and Periods)

Tags: javascript, regex

I need a regular expression that will be able to detect:

```
https://s-dPICS-sac323.domain.com/a12_hyJ_k87ds_x.jpg
```

Will this code do it:

```
var x = /(https:\/\/[A-Za-z0-9.-]*PICS[A-Za-z0-9._\/]*\.jpg)/g;
```

Will this be able to detect something along the lines of:

Note: everything except **https://**, **PICS**, **domain.com**, and  **.jpg** are random alpha-numeric characters for this example. I'm trying to detect all of the rest of the characters.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Aye, it didn't work, and it's been a long time since I've had to use regex. I'm rusty.

Comment: What do you mean by "detect"? Do you want to just validate that a given URL matches the pattern, or do you want to extract the variable part(s)? (Also, if it's not working, maybe show the next few lines of code for how you try to use it.)

Comment: edited the original post with more details

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
/https:\/\/[a-z0-9.-]*photos[\w.\/-]*\.jpg/i
```

Demo: http://rubular.com/r/flmf92C3T2

Comment: Didn't work, but thanks for the attempt. I edited the original post with more details

Comment: Thank you for that. It didn't fix the problem, but the RegExp checker says it's valid, and I can follow what you did there. There must be another bug (or set of bugs) in my code that I have yet to find. Thank you for this. Marking your answer right, since it fixes this bug.

Comment: Although in this case I think it’s ok, isn’t it a bit dodgy to try to infer Javascript regex behavior using Ruby regexes?

Comment: @tchrist I figured the regex and the string it's matching were simple enough to just do that.

Answer (score 0):

<del>Don't escape normal slashes, they aren't magic characters.</del>

```
    /https:\/\/[\w.-]+PICS[\w.\/-]+\.domain\.com/[\w.\/-]+\.jpg/
```

Comment: Uhhh, normal slashes are magic characters when you're defining a regex using the `/regex here/` notation like the OP was.

Comment: Didn't work, but thanks for the attempt. I edited the original post with more details

Comment: @jfriend thanks for that info. But do you also have to escape slashes inside character classes?

Comment: @kaepp You can get away with it if they are in char classes, but I escape them anyways just to be on the safe side.

Comment: I'm unsure if they have to be escaped inside of character classes, but it seems risky not too as I don't know if it would work in every situation.  I know that syntax highlighters get messed up when you don't escape them and regex test sites like rubular.com say you have to escape them.  So, I escape them to be safe.  Chrome works without escaping them inside of [].

Answer (score 0):

`/(https:\/\/[A-z0-9.-]*PICS[A-z0-9.-]*domain\.com[A-z0-9.-/_]*\.jpg)/` will match "https://s-dPICS-sac323.domain.com/a12_hyJ_k87ds_x.jpg".

And `/(https:\/\/[A-z0-9.-]*photos[A-z0-9/.-]*\.jpg)/` will match "https://fbcdn-sphotos-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-snc3/12868_695309462154_5301742_40115272_5760577_n.jpg" with **https://**, **photos**, and **.jpg** being constant.

Is there something more you need out of it? Give it a try at regexpal.com